# Mapnik using node js gives error

Tags: xml, node.js, mapnik

I am trying to run a sample mapnik code, using node js which is posted on http://mapnik.org/. I have installed mapnik,node using homebrew. Created a sample folder 'test', in it a main.js and stylesheet.xml.But 'node main.js ' gives me the following error:

[Mine:~/Desktop] macmini8 $node test/main.js

/Users/macmini8/Desktop/test/main.js:8  if (err) throw err;              ^  Error: Could not create datasource. Required parameter 'type' is missing  encountered during parsing of layer 'world' in Layer of 'test/stylesheet.xml'     at Error (native)

There is no 'type' in the given stylesheet.I am a newbie. So, Can anyone tell me where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Forgot to add 'type' parameter inside the datasource

```
<Datasource>
            <Parameter name="type">shape</Parameter>
            <Parameter name="file">place.shp</Parameter>
</Datasource>
```

Comment: The Mapnik landing page does not have the type parameter in the example. Is it required? Or is there a way to get it to work without it?